# how to update the log message about failure of service

Tags: rhel, systemd, logs, services, rsyslog

I configured the service - `calc_mem.service`

as the following

```
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=3
```

the configuration above should do the following

*the service have 3 retries when service exit with error
and before service start it will wait 5 seconds*

also we want to update the `/var/log/message` about any retry from the service

for example

lets say we start the service , and service fail 
so it will try the first try , and on the first try service successfully started

is it possible to write the fail of service start to `/var/log/message` ?

note - we have redhat Linux machine version - 7.2

Comment: Hmm, what is in /var/log/messages already? Does it show "Starting" and "Started" lines for calc_mem.service?

Comment: please edit to confirm your version number of RHEL or CentOS

Comment: my redhat version is 7.2

Comment: I guess its show service started , but for sure its not show when its fail or not start correctly

Comment: Thanks. I think you should edit to show what those messages look like. Then, what does the RHEL rsyslog.conf look like? I wonder if you see the messages in /var/log/error or /var/log/warn or something like that.

Comment: As can be seen from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289629/5132 as just one example, this stuff _is_ logged in the journal.  This is really an rsyslog problem, not a systemd one.